# Use pd.to_datetime for a column/pandas.series over all rows which are in list format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have tried to solve my problem for many hours, but somehow I dont get the solutions right.
I have a pandas dataframe which comprises a column of dates, which are in turn stored as lists for each row.

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

gives me the error: unhashable type: 'list'

My dataframe looks like this:

```
0    [February 28, 2013 Thursday]
1       [November 2, 2012 Friday]
2         [July 31, 2012 Tuesday]
3         [May 10, 2012 Thursday]
4       [June 23, 2004 Wednesday]
```

as such, each row is a list, but each list only contains one string. I want to convert this one string within each row to datetime format (just like 02-28-2013) in the dataframe so that I can perform date operations.

How can I convert the column in a way that the pd.to_datetime command can be executed?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

i create my DataFrame like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) 
df.date=[['01-01-2013'], ['2-2-2015'], ['July 31, 2012']]
```

I used to write some random dates, but it's also a pandas with lists.

```
>>> df.date
0       [01-01-2013]
1         [2-2-2015]
2    [July 31, 2012]
```

You have to access the elements in the list, so simply use a *lambda function*

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date.apply(lambda x: x[0]))

>>> df.date
0   2013-01-01
1   2015-02-02
2   2012-07-31
```